# How to use input type file in angular 8 json schema form?

Tags: angular8

I'm trying to add input type="file" from angular 8 json schema form. My json is:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
    "document": {
        "type": "file"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "document"
  ]
}
```

And my form in html is:

```
<json-schema-form framework="material-design" [loadExternalAssets]="false" [schema]="jsonFormObject"
        (onSubmit)="createUserDocument($event)"></json-schema-form>
```

I'm using angular 8. Also select multiple and textarea is not working. Please help. Thanks in advance